# Control PWR Led on Raspberry 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I read quite a few articels that say that the power led is now hardwired on
a raspy 3 device but some say it is somehow possible (but do not give specific
answers).

My question(s): 
1.) is it possible to control the led via python and how.
2.) if not then can I permanently disable it?

Comment: *"1.) is it possible to control the led via python and how."* Check [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44168/how-can-i-control-the-red-led-again) for starters. *"2.) if not then can I permanently disable it?"* De-solder it, short it out with a solder blob or replace it with an SMD diode or resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power LED is now also acting as a low-voltage indicator now. It is possible (however not trivial) to use it as an output but then the low-voltage indicaton is not working anymore. If I understand it correctly, the devs need to come up with a solution, so not much "normal" users can do for now.

There is an open issue on their bugtracker where you can get a bit more info: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1332

In general, as soon as the devs make it possible to control the power LED, there should be a file named `/boot/overlays/pi3-pwr-led.dtbo`. Currently, there isn't.

You can also have a look at one of the bare-metal environments and see if they have come up with a work-around.
https://github.com/rsta2/circle
https://github.com/vanvught/rpidmx512

Comment: So simple answer is no... Anyway thank  you for the hints. I'm not skilled enough to tamper with the base kernel options.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems so for non-experts (as I am as well). The devs do not give this any high priority. It's on the "nice to have" list.